# How to extract text from file (with in script tag) using Python or beautifulsoup

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Could you please help me with this little thing. I am looking to extract **lat and lng** value from the below code in SCRIPT tag(not in Body) using Beautiful soup(Python) or python. I am new to Python and blog are recommending to use Beautiful soup for extracting.

I want these two values **lat: 21.25335 , lng: 81.649445**
I am using regular expression for this . My regular expresion **"^l([a-t])(:) ([0-9])([^,]+)"**

Check this link for Regular expression and html file - 
http://regexr.com/3glde

I get those two value with this regular expression but i want only those lat and lng value (numeric part ) to be stored in variable .

Here below is my python code which I am using

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("^[l]([a-t])([a-t])(\:) ([0-9])([^,]+)")

for i, line in enumerate(open('C:\hile_text.html')):
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
        print 'Found on line %s: %s' % (i+1, match.groups())
```

Output:

- Found on line 3218: ('a', 't', ':', '2', '1.244791')
- Found on line 3219: ('n', 'g', ':', '8', '1.643486')

I want only those numeric value as output like 21.25335,81.649445 and want to store these values in variables or else you can provide alternate code to this.

plzz soon help me out .Thanks in anticipation.

This is the script tag in html file .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.mapDivId = 'map0Div';
    window.map0Div = {
    lat: 21.25335,
    lng: 81.649445,
    zoom: null,
    locId: 5897747,
    geoId: 297595,
    isAttraction: false,
    isEatery: true,
    isLodging: false,
    isNeighborhood: false,
    title: "Aman Age Roll & Chicken ",
    homeIcon: true,
    url: "/Restaurant_Review-g297595-d5897747-Reviews-Aman_Age_Roll_Chicken-Raipur_Raipur_District_Chhattisgarh.html",
    minPins: [
    ['hotel', 20],
    ['restaurant', 20],
    ['attraction', 20],
    ['vacation_rental', 0]       ],
    units: 'km',
    geoMap: false,
    tabletFullSite: false,
    reuseHoverDivs: false,
    noSponsors: true    };
    ta.store('infobox_js', 'https://static.tacdn.com/js3/infobox-c-v21051733989b.js');
    ta.store("ta.maps.apiKey", "");
    (function() {
    var onload = function() {
    if (window.location.hash == "#MAPVIEW") {
    ta.run("ta.mapsv2.Factory.handleHashLocation", {}, true);
    }
    }
    if (window.addEventListener) {
    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
    window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    ta.run("ta.mapsv2.Factory.handleHashLocation", {}, false);
    }, false);
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', onload, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', onload);
    }
    })();
    ta.store("mapsv2.show_sidebar", true);
    ta.store('mapsv2_restaurant_reservation_js', ["https://static.tacdn.com/js3/ta-mapsv2-restaurant-reservation-c-v2430632369b.js"]);
    ta.store('mapsv2.typeahead_css', "https://static.tacdn.com/css2/maps_typeahead-v21940478230b.css");
    // Feature gate VR price pins on SRP map. VRC-14803
    ta.store('mapsv2.vr_srp_map_price_enabled', true);
    ta.store('mapsv2.geoName', 'Raipur');
    ta.store('mapsv2.map_addressnotfound', "Address not found");     ta.store('mapsv2.map_addressnotfound3', "We couldn\'t find that location near {0}.  Please try another search.");     ta.store('mapsv2.directions', "Directions from {0} to {1}");     ta.store('mapsv2.enter_dates', "Enter dates for best prices");     ta.store('mapsv2.best_prices', "Best prices for your stay");     ta.store('mapsv2.list_accom', "List of accommodations");     ta.store('mapsv2.list_hotels', "List of hotels");     ta.store('mapsv2.list_vrs', "List of holiday rentals");     ta.store('mapsv2.more_accom', "More accommodations");     ta.store('mapsv2.more_hotels', "More hotels");      ta.store('mapsv2.more_vrs', "More Holiday Homes");     ta.store('mapsv2.sold_out_on_1', "SOLD OUT on 1 site");     ta.store('mapsv2.sold_out_on_y', "SOLD OUT on 2 sites");   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is a bit messed up.
`^l` says you are trying to match an 'l' that is the very first character on a line.

`^\s+(l[an][gt])(:\s+)(\d+\.\d+)` would work better.  Checkout an regerx analyzer tool such as http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws  to get a breakdown of what is happening.

Here is a breakdown

`Sequence: match all of the followings in order
BeginOfLine
Repeat
WhiteSpaceCharacter
one or more times
CapturingGroup
 GroupNumber:1
  Sequence: match all of the followings in order
   l
   AnyCharIn[ a n]
   AnyCharIn[ g t]
CapturingGroup
 GroupNumber:2
  Sequence: match all of the followings in order
   :
   Repeat
    WhiteSpaceCharacter
    one or more times
CapturingGroup
 GroupNumber:3
  Sequence: match all of the followings in order
   Repeat
    Digit
    one or more times
   .
   Repeat
    Digit
    one or more times`

Comment: "(l[an][gt])(:\s+)(\d+\.\d+)" this expression is working now